# Find average electron velocity on copper bus bar(um/s)

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits

I was given this problem:

A current of 1,400 Amps flows in a copper bus bar.  The bus bar is 0.6 cm wide by 9 cm long.  You can assume the current flows only on the surface of the bus bar (so you can ignore the “depth” of the copper bar).  Find the average electron velocity in the copper bus bar.

Copper has a free electron density of 1029 electrons/cubic meter.

Charge C = 1.6022e-19 Coulombs

Current = i = charge times velocity

n = amounts of charge per volume

**However because Im asked to ignore the third dimension of the copper bar 
 Im not sure if Im solving this problem correctly**

$$\begin{align}
i &= \frac{dq}{dt} \ldots \frac{n(volume)q}{dt}=\frac{n{A(V_dt)q}}{dt} \\
i &= \frac{n*A*V_dq}{dt} \\
V_d&=1.618E^{-8}um/s
\end{align}$$

Comment: Better on physics or electrical ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that your free electron density isn't correct.

Unless I have misunderstood your question, the equation you need is,

$$v_e = \frac{I}{nAq}$$
$$v_e = \frac{1400}{1029\times 5.4\times10^{-6} \times 1.6\times10^{-19}}$$
$$v_e = 1.572\times10^{25} \text{ m/s}$$
$$v_e = 1.572\times10^{31} \text{ $\mu$m/s}$$

$n$ should be about $8.5\times10^{28}$, though, which makes the actual answer:

$$v_e = \frac{1400}{8.5\times10^{28}\times 5.4\times10^{-6} \times 1.6\times10^{-19}}$$
$$v_e = 0.01906 \text{ m/s}$$
$$v_e = 1.906\times10^{-8} \text{ $\mu$m/s}$$